# Why the radius equals $2$ in the Wigner semicircle law?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

I'm using the notations of the [Erdős-Yau book](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~htyau/RM-Aug-2016.pdf). On page 11:
Let $H$ be an $N \times N$ real symmetric or complex Hermitian *[Wigner matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix#Generalizations)*, where the upper triangle entries of $H$ are independent, the entries are centered $\mathbb{E}h_{ij}=0$, and the variances are $\mathbb{E}|h_{ij}|^2=N^{-1}$. Let $\lambda_1\leq\dots\leq\lambda_N$ denote the eigenvalues of $H$. The [*Wigner semicircle law*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WignersSemicircleLaw.html) states that for any fixed $a\leq b$ real numbers, we have
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\#\{i: \lambda_i \in [a,b]\}}{N} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_a^b \sqrt{(4-x^2)_+},
$$
where $(\alpha)_+ := \max\{0,\alpha\}$ denotes the *positive part of a number* $\alpha$.

This implies that as $N$ goes to infinity, all the eigenvalues are in the interval $[-2,2]$. There are two proofs in the above linked book for this statement. The first uses *the moment method*, and the second uses the *Stieltjes transform method*, but from these proofs it is not clear for me, how $4$ appears in the integrand above. I'm pretty sure that there is a probabilstic reasoning for this, and it would not be surprising if it is because of some basic properties of moments for example, but I just can't figure it out.

> Why the radius of the semicircle equals $2$ in the Wigner semicircle law?

Comment: I didn’t know about this book by Erdos and Yau. Thanks for posting.